# Heroku NodeJS Deployment Error - Failed at start script

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, deployment

I’m getting a weird error when I am trying to deploy my node app to Heroku - Failed at the crm-api@1.0.0 start script.

Here is a link to my repo - https://github.com/fishj123/CRM-API

Here are my error logs:

```
2019-07-06T11:21:55.154778+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
2019-07-06T11:21:55.154780+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:15:25)
2019-07-06T11:21:55.154782+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
2019-07-06T11:21:55.154783+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
2019-07-06T11:21:55.154785+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
2019-07-06T11:21:55.163928+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-07-06T11:21:55.164396+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-07-06T11:21:55.165476+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! crm-api@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
2019-07-06T11:21:55.165587+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-07-06T11:21:55.165787+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-07-06T11:21:55.165902+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the crm-api@1.0.0 start script.
2019-07-06T11:21:55.165998+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-07-06T11:21:55.175793+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-06T11:21:55.175951+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-07-06T11:21:55.176025+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-07-06T11_21_55_167Z-debug.log
2019-07-06T11:21:55.236179+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-07-06T11:45:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user jackfisher94@live.co.uk
2019-07-06T11:46:18.166281+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-07-06T11:46:17.778489+00:00 app[api]: Release v9 created by user jackfisher94@live.co.uk
2019-07-06T11:46:17.778489+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 24a98021 by user jackfisher94@live.co.uk
2019-07-06T11:46:18.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-07-06T11:46:20.394900+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-07-06T11:46:22.581404+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-06T11:46:22.581421+00:00 app[web.1]: > crm-api@1.0.0 start /app
2019-07-06T11:46:22.581423+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2019-07-06T11:46:22.581425+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-06T11:46:23.332661+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-07-06T11:46:23.317305+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-07-06T11:46:23.251977+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
2019-07-06T11:46:23.252009+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-07-06T11:46:23.252011+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-07-06T11:46:23.252012+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-06T11:46:23.252014+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../models/Client'
2019-07-06T11:46:23.252016+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
2019-07-06T11:46:23.252017+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
2019-07-06T11:46:23.252019+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
2019-07-06T11:46:23.252020+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
2019-07-06T11:46:23.252022+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/routes/clients.js:3:30)
2019-07-06T11:46:23.252023+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
2019-07-06T11:46:23.252025+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
2019-07-06T11:46:23.252026+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
2019-07-06T11:46:23.252028+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
2019-07-06T11:46:23.252029+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
2019-07-06T11:46:23.252031+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
2019-07-06T11:46:23.252032+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
2019-07-06T11:46:23.252034+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:15:25)
2019-07-06T11:46:23.252035+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
2019-07-06T11:46:23.252037+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
2019-07-06T11:46:23.252038+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
2019-07-06T11:46:23.270836+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-07-06T11:46:23.271510+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-07-06T11:46:23.273284+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! crm-api@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
2019-07-06T11:46:23.273484+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-07-06T11:46:23.273865+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-07-06T11:46:23.274101+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the crm-api@1.0.0 start script.
2019-07-06T11:46:23.274283+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-07-06T11:46:23.280471+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-06T11:46:23.280632+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-07-06T11:46:23.280744+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-07-06T11_46_23_276Z-debug.log
2019-07-06T11:46:23.345339+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-07-06T11:46:25.436499+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-07-06T11:46:27.251643+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-06T11:46:27.251668+00:00 app[web.1]: > crm-api@1.0.0 start /app
2019-07-06T11:46:27.251671+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2019-07-06T11:46:27.251673+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-06T11:46:27.989715+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
2019-07-06T11:46:27.989746+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-07-06T11:46:27.989748+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-07-06T11:46:27.989750+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-06T11:46:27.989751+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../models/Client'
2019-07-06T11:46:27.989753+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
2019-07-06T11:46:27.989755+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
2019-07-06T11:46:27.989756+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
2019-07-06T11:46:27.989758+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
2019-07-06T11:46:27.989759+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/routes/clients.js:3:30)
2019-07-06T11:46:27.989761+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
2019-07-06T11:46:27.989762+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
2019-07-06T11:46:27.989764+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
2019-07-06T11:46:27.989765+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
2019-07-06T11:46:27.989767+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
2019-07-06T11:46:27.989768+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
2019-07-06T11:46:27.989769+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
2019-07-06T11:46:27.989771+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:15:25)
2019-07-06T11:46:27.989772+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
2019-07-06T11:46:27.989774+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
2019-07-06T11:46:27.989775+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
2019-07-06T11:46:27.999517+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-07-06T11:46:28.000249+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-07-06T11:46:28.002067+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! crm-api@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
2019-07-06T11:46:28.002366+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-07-06T11:46:28.002754+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-07-06T11:46:28.003069+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the crm-api@1.0.0 start script.
2019-07-06T11:46:28.003349+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-07-06T11:46:28.010396+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-06T11:46:28.010549+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-07-06T11:46:28.010665+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-07-06T11_46_28_004Z-debug.log
2019-07-06T11:46:28.077026+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-07-06T11:46:28.055661+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-07-06T11:46:29.998976+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=enigmatic-everglades-16570.herokuapp.com request_id=7ed55230-9061-44af-b4ff-63c1cd6410b9 fwd="92.233.88.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-07-06T11:46:31.114248+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=enigmatic-everglades-16570.herokuapp.com request_id=da65875b-1252-43df-9128-c170d3b3a8a0 fwd="92.233.88.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Things I have tried so far:

1. Update NPM/NodeJS
2. Delete Node Modules and Package.lock.json, clear cache, npm install
3. Run start script locally (node app.js)
4. npm run app.js

The project is working perfectly on my local version so I can’t work out why the start script is failing. Would really appreciate any advice.

Thanks

Comment: Not that weird, given that a) it says `Error: Cannot find module '../models/Client'` and b) the `models` folder of your repo is empty

Comment: Ok 1. I'm an idiot. 2. Why is my models folder empty? Why is git ignoring it?? My gitignore file only has: .env

node_modules/

Comment: Did you add the files inside the folder before committing?